# Thymeleaf with Google Charts

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need help with charts, well, I'm doing a report for a client that will contain some very simple information in the form of charts, and studying the charts currently available, I found Google Charts interesting, because apparently it is very simple to handle. Well, I went to Google's website and got the HTML code and just pasted it into the report I'm making for the client, the strange thing is that simply the document in the part where the graph should have had it was blank. Searching the internet I didn't find any problems similar to that of Google Charts being blank in Thymeleaf. Does anyone have any idea what it might be?
Note: Creating only one .HTML web page, the graphic is successfully displayed, but when inserted in Thymeleaf despite being in .HTML when converting to PDF, it is blank.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Lucros x Despesas</title>
    <style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<h1>Automóveis </h1>

<h5>Acompanhe abaixo o relatório Lucros x Despesas</h5>
<div style="font-size: 15px;">
<b>Filtros Utilizados:</b>
<span th:text="${'Data Inicial    - ' + dataInicialPesquisa}"></span>
<span th:text="${' | Data Final    - ' + dataFinalPesquisa}"></span>
</div>
<p th:text="${'Name    : ' + name}"></p>
<p th:text="${'Age     :' + age}"></p>
<p th:text="${'Country : ' + country}"></p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${age}"></td>
        <td th:text="${country}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h4 th:text="${erroMsg}"></h4>

<p><b>Congratualations!! It's done</b></p>

<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
        ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
        ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
        ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

@Edit

Methods I use to create the PDF:

```
    public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> getPdf(LucroDespesaModel details, PesquisaLucroDespesaPeriodoModel model) throws IOException, DocumentException, ParseException {
        Context context = new Context();
        System.out.println(details);
        System.out.println(">PDF: " + details.getPeriodoPesquisa());
        Document doc=new Document(PageSize.A4);
        DateUtil dt = new DateUtil();
        System.out.println("data: " + dt.getDataAtual(model.getDataInicial()));
        context.setVariable("dataInicialPesquisa",dt.getDataAtual(model.getDataInicial()));
        context.setVariable("dataFinalPesquisa",dt.getDataAtual(model.getDataFinal()));
        context.setVariable("name",details.getPeriodoPesquisa());
        
        context.setVariable("age",details.getValorDespesaTotal());
        context.setVariable("country",details.getValorLucroTotal());
        if(details.getValorDespesaTotal() == null ||
                details.getValorLucroTotal() == null
                || details == null || model == null) {
            context.setVariable("erroMsg", "Nenhum valor foi encontrado dentro do período selecionado");
        } else {
            context.setVariable("erroMsg", "");
        }

        String htmlContentToRender = templateEngine.process("pdf-template", context);
        String xHtml = null;
        xHtml = xhtmlConvert(htmlContentToRender);

        //Do the below steps in a service call this is to send to angular
        htmlDoc=new StringReader(xHtml);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,outputStream);
        doc.open();
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter,doc,htmlDoc);
        doc.addAuthor("F1 Automóveis - Gênesis Desenvolvedora");
        doc.addCreationDate();
        doc.addCreator("Sistema F1 Automóveis - Gênesis Desenvolvedora");
        doc.addKeywords("Relatório de Lucros x Despesas");
        doc.addTitle("Relatório Lucros x Despesas - " + dt.getDataAtual(model.getDataInicial()) + " a "
        + dt.getDataAtual(model.getDataFinal()));
        doc.addProducer();
        doc.close();

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + "Downloads.pdf" + "\"")
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(outputStream.toByteArray()));

    }
//TO-DO in a service class
    private String xhtmlConvert(String html) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setXHTML(true);
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, outputStream);
        return outputStream.toString("UTF-8");
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that everything works correctly - _except_ for when you try to create a PDF from the web page? How are you trying to create the PDF? If you _only_ want to create a PDF, then why do you need Thymeleaf?

Comment: @andrewjames Sorry for my bad English friend, actually creating the PDF correctly, it displays everything I define in it, except Google Charts, it is not being displayed is blank.
You can see the model of how it is coming out at: https://prnt.sc/11zbj4z note that below the Congratualations should have the graph.

Comment: How do you create the PDF?

Comment: @andrewjames I edited the topic and added the method where I create.

Comment: You are trying to generate your PDF from an HTML page, generated by Thymeleaf. That HTML pages does not contain a chart. It only contains some JavaScript which will eventually generate a chart when the JS is executed in a browser engine. The JavaScript is never executed - and therefore a chart is never created - and therefore it cannot be displayed in the PDF. That is why you only see the static HTML content in your PDF.

Comment: (I believe you would have the same problem if you tried to use an actual web page URL, also, because the URL would only fetch the "page source" HTML - but I have not tested that.)

Comment: @andrewjames I understand, but would there be any way for me to issue this PDF report with graphics? In the case of a simple statement, would a very simple graphic have some way of being output in the PDF?

Comment: My suggestions: (1) You can ask a new, more specific question, based on this new information. Maybe someone else has a creative solution. (2) There are various other Java-based charting tools which you can try - and there are already many questions on SO about how to generate PDFs containing charts, using those other tools ([here](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is one popular tool).